# How to constrain parameter values using fminsearch (or alternative) in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Is there any way to force fminsearch in pracma to constrain its search to a designated parameter subspace?  If not, is there an alternative to fminsearch that could do that?

My actual case has a lot of complexity that doesn't relate to this question so here is a simple case instead. Because parameter values are unconstrained, fminsearch tries out invalid values in the second example at the bottom, and this leads to errors. These errors could be avoided if there were a way to tell fminsearch that the first param must be nonnegative, but how to do that?

```
library( pracma )

fit_param   = function(D) {
    return( fminsearch( error_fn, c(5,1), D=D ) )
}

error_fn    = function( params, D ) {
    pred_y  = replicate( nrow(D), predict(params,D) )
    SSE     = sum((D$y-pred_y)^2)
    return( SSE )
}

predict     = function( params, D ) {
    if ( params[1]<0 ) {
        writeLines( paste( "invalid parameter value for parameter 1:", params[1] ) )
    }
    pred    = sqrt(params[1]) * D$x + params[2]
    return( pred )
}

true_model  = function( D, params ) {
    return( predict( params, D ) )
}

D   = data.frame( x=replicate(100,rand()) )
D$y = true_model( D, c( 5, 1 ) )
    fit_param( D ) # works
    D$y = true_model( D, c( .5, 1 ) )
fit_param( D ) # doesn't work - comes too close to zero and tries out negative values, resulting in errors
```

Comment: base R: `optim(...,method="L-BFGS-B", ...)` or see the `optimx` package or the `nloptr` package.

Comment: Ben, thanks for the useful references. Well, it turns out the complexity I left out in order to produce simple & reproducible code is actually relevant. :(  In my actual model gradients are not available.  If I understand right that means BFGS will not apply to my case, correct?  Am I right in thinking that nelder-mead in nloptr would be my best choice in this case, since optim and optimx don't seem to have options that allow box constraints without gradients?

Comment: L-BFGS-B doesn't actually need gradients, because `optim` automatically reverts to finite-difference approximates to the gradient if `gr` is not specified (on the other hand, `optimx` does require explicit gradients for the gradient-based optimizers).  Or as you suggest you could use nelder-mead (or BOBYQA) in nloptr ...

Comment: Cool - thanks! I want to make this my accepted answer, but I can't cuz it's a comment!

Comment: if I don't get around to it soon, it's fine with me if you post this as an answer yourself and then accept it.